# Not able to resize image using jQuery aeImageResize function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery aeImageResize function to resize my image but it keep saying Uncought Type error: Object has no method aeImageResize when I debug using chrome inspect element. Yes I am getting the testing alert message and I do have jQuery library before this script. The jQuery library I am using is http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js.

```
$(function() {
alert("Testing");
$('#resizeme IMG').aeImageResize({height: 507, width: 338});

});
```

HTML code:

```
<img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="" class="resizeme" />
<img src="upload/75.jpg" alt="random image" class="resizeme" />
<img src="upload/img4.jpg" alt="random image" class="resizeme" />    
<img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="" class="resizeme" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to include the plugin:
https://raw.github.com/adeelejaz/jquery-image-resize/master/jquery.ae.image.resize.js

And there is also a little mistake in your javascript.
you try to select an image nested in an object with the id "resizeme".
try `$('img.resizeme').aeImageResize({height: 507, width: 338});` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ae Image Resize is a plugin.  Have you downloaded the plugin, and are you including a reference to the plugin?  http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/aeImageResize